# Not able to post data to suitelet from client in suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite

I am calling suitlet form client but it's not posting data .. from client to suitelet.. but log is printed that post method was called.. just data is not passing. Am i doing something wrong. Log hello is printed but no data

```
var postData={'hello':'hi'};

    postData=JSON.stringify(postData);

    var header=[];
    header['Content-Type']='application/json';

    var suiteletURL = urlresolve.resolveScript({
        scriptId:'customscript2289', 
        deploymentId: 'customdeploy1'
        });

    try{

    var response=https.post({
        url: suiteletURL, 
        headers:header,
        body:postData
      });

    var newSFID=response.body;
    alert(newSFID);

    }catch(ee){
      alert(JSON.stringify(ee));
    }
```

In suitelet

```
if (context.request.method == 'POST'){  

            log.debug ({
             title: 'hello',
             details: context.request.parameters.test
             });

             //createReturnAuthorization(record);


        }
```

Comment: try using log.debug `({ title: 'hello', details: context.request })` in your suitelet log or *context.request.body* to be precise .

Comment: Nothing is coming in log also.. only title hello, no data

Comment: Have you changed your script logs view and removed details column?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this details: context.request.parameters.test try this details: context.request.parameters.hello

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.